# DTS.dll not registering properly in C# ASP.Net Visual Studio 2008 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dts

I've inherited an application from a former co-worker. It's a C# ASP.Net Web Application. When I try to compile it in Visual Studio 2008, it complains that it can't find the DTS namespace. So I added the DTS.dll file to References from C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn. When I do that, all compile errors go away, but I get two warnings that look pretty nasty to me:

"Cannot find wrapper assembly for the type library DTSLib. Verify that (1) the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the COM component is 32-bit, your target platform cannot be 64-bit."

and

"The referenced component DTSLib could not be found"

Also, DTSLib in the References in Solution Explorer has a yellow exclamation point next to it.

First, am I correct to be concerned about this? Second, if so, how do I solve it? It's not a question of the bitness, since I'm working on a 64-bit machine and took the dll from Program Files, not Program Files (x86).

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

@Melanie: DTS has a some support issues in 2008, due to the creation of SQL Server Integration Services. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500440%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I hope the support issues have been ironed out if the client is also on SQL Server 2008 R2.

What the most likely problem is is you do not have the packages fully installed. This is rather easy and handled by following the instructions at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143755(v=sql.105).aspx - essentially a backward compatibility "hack".

The problem may be the failure to register some COM components, which may or may not exist on drive. Most likely do, as you can follow the instructions above, but they may also be copied and registered at the time.

The reason I asked which version is you would have had to do a repair if they were still on a version like SQL Server 2000.

I would recommend the company invest some time in updating to SSIS, as they are not going to be able to migrate to SQL Server 2012 or 2014 if they still wish to do DTS. It was deprecated in SQL Server 2005, support reduced further in 2008 (with some limitations) and gone as of SQL Server 2012. Actually, there is a hack they might be able to do, but I have not tested it (and do not recommend it, if so).